# How to toggle in console command in Left 4 Dead 2?

Tags: left-4-dead-2

I have this command then how to toggle.

`bind p "noclip"`

when I press P, it activate noclip, then when I press P again it will off.

Answer (score 1):

The [`bind`](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Bind) command allows other console commands to be toggled on and off with one keypress.

To toggle noclip:

```
bind "p" "noclip"
```

The quotes are strongly recommended so the command will never fail even if a special character is used. Be sure to turn cheats on first by typing `sv_cheats 1` in the console.

Comment: noclip isn't set with `noclip 1` it's set just with `noclip`, so there is no reason to use `BindToggle`. just `bind p "noclip"` will be sufficient to toggle it. I expect it's not working because the guy needs to enable cheats with `sv_cheats 1`, and obviously it will only work in single player games.

Comment: @SLC That's true. I overlooked that. I'll edit my answer to make the correction.

Answer (score -1):

If you cannot use `bindtoggle` (`bindtoggle p "sv_cheats 0 1"`), you can try a "cascading alias" setup. What you do is bind the key to your own alias command:

```
alias fooAlias "fooAliasEnable"
alias fooAliasEnable "sv_cheats 1; alias fooAlias fooAliasDisable"
alias fooAliasDisable "sv_cheats 0; alias fooAlias fooAliasEnable"
bind p fooAlias
```

So what happens is the key is bound to a single alias, that alias calls a second alias, and that second alias resets the first alias to a different second alias. This can be extended beyond 2 and so is more general than a simple toggle.

Not actually tested, but check google for more info.